# how to make email templates in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I want to make a email template to use in Joomla back-end. does it possible? how?
I looked up at Joomla docs and didn't find my answer. I use Joomla 2.5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly upgrade your Joomla version to the latest 2.5.x version

As for the e-mail template, you will need to install a component that allows such a feature, like a Newsletter component. I personally would recommend [JNews](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/11585), however more can be found at the following link:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter

Hope this helps